# Кроссдоменный запрос ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Помогите сделать кроссдоменный запрос, я не могу понять что мне нужно прописать в шапке запроса?

```js
 var dataPromo = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://dev.leed.steko.com.ua/api/takedata-promo',
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataPromo,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
```

Comment: Вам нужно на удаленном сервере прописывать `allow-origin` либо проксировать запросы на своем сервере.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev тут еще дело в том что сам `js` криво написан

Comment: @TsyklopМожете поправить в где именно криво)?

Comment: а смысл js поправлять, если один хрен не будет работать?

Answer (score 0):

Сделать запрос так:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://dev.leed.steko.com.ua/api/takedata-promo',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
```

Но этого не достаточно что бы он сработал.

на сервере, куда вы обращаетесь нужно выставить несколько заголовков.

К примеру в `php` так:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

Взято [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Можно:

Есть небольшой трюк с PHP. И этот трюк будет работать не только с Google, но и с любыми сайтами, к которым у вас нет доступа и вы не можете добавить Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Нам нужно создать PHP-файл (например. getContentFromUrl.php) на нашем сервере и сделать обращение к нему.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$ext_url = $_POST['ext_url'];

echo file_get_contents($ext_url);

?>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'getContentFromUrl.php', // link to your PHP file
    data: {
        // url куда наш сервер будет отправлять запрос, который мы не можем сделать через AJAX
        'ext_url': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // теперь мы можем взять любые данные из внешнего url, потому что у нас есть вся страница
        var $h1 = $(data).find('h1').html();

        $('h1').text($h1);
    },
    error:function() {
        console.log('Error');
    }
});
```

**Как это работает:**

1. Ваш браузер с помощью JS отправит запрос на ваш сервер
2. Ваш сервер отправит запрос на любой другой сервер и получит ответ
3. Ваш сервер отправит этот ответ в ваш JS файл

И мы можем добавить event типа onClick на кнопку. Надеюсь, это поможет!